# MySQL Query: right syntax to use for `SELECT users.(foo, bar)`

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the MySQL code.

```
SELECT users.(user_id, pic, first_name, last_name, username), 
           comments.(id, user_id, date_created)
FROM users
INNER JOIN comments ON users.user_id = comments.user_id 
WHERE comments.user_id = '$user_id'
GROUP BY comments.date_created
```

I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(user_id, pic, first_name, last_name, username), comments.(id, user_id, date_created)' at line 1

Comment: On a slightly different note, you should look into using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of dynamic SQL commands. It's a safer alternative, and often simpler than all the nasty escaping that you have to do otherwise. There are many tutorials around.  Here's a couple to get you started: [Prepared Statements in PHP and MySQLi](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) and [Developing MySQL Database Applications With PHP](http://developers.sun.com/databases/articles/mysql_php1.html).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.pic, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username, c.id, c.user_id AS comment_user_id, c.date_created
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN comments c ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
    WHERE c.user_id = '$user_id'
    GROUP BY c.date_created
```

Answer (score 1):

```
users.(user_id, pic, first_name, last_name, username)
```

should be

```
users.user_id,users.pic, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.username
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be as already posted in two answers, but if you will have problems with JOIN you can simply do it so.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.pic, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username,
       c.id, c.user_id, c.date_created
FROM users u, comments c
WHERE u.user_id = c.user_id AND c.user_id = '$user_id'
GROUP BY c.date_created;
```

That should clear things up. Sorry for repeating most of the query, but I just hate JOINs ;)